# Using PATCH or PUT deletes the object - DJango

Tags: django, http

I'm using Django Rest as my BE server, and have created a Chat object that holds messages and participants, and I manage to create objects as expected using the POST method and get these objects using the GET method - so far so good.

But when I try to update the participants by doing a PUT or PATCH requests on the object with different participants, the object just gets deleted (another GET request does not bring that object back as a result).

models.py (the messages have foreign key to the Chat object but this is not the issue so i will leave it out):

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='chats', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="chat_app:chat-detail", lookup_field='id')
    participants = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,
                                                       view_name="user_app:profile-detail",
                                                       queryset=Profile.objects.all(),
                                                       lookup_field='id', required=False)
    messages = MessageSerializer(many=True, required=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = ('id', 'messages', 'participants', 'url')
        read_only = ('id', )
```

views.py:

```
class ChatViewSet(BaseModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ChatSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
    lookup_field = "id"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.profile.chats
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
some logs from the server (no errors):

```
 HTTP POST /api/chat/ 201 [0.04, 172.23.0.1:49202]
 HTTP GET /api/chat/3/ 200 [0.03, 172.23.0.1:49202]
 HTTP PUT /api/chat/3/ 200 [0.06, 172.23.0.1:49202]
 Not Found: /api/chat/3/
```

you can see that i POST (works fine) then GET the chat object that was created (id - 3) and then PUT (which doesnt throw an error) and finally GET again is Not Found (PUT deleted it)

Comment: A PUT actually removes the "old" object, since you "put" a new one there. A patch should not do that.

Comment: Yes but a PUT should also put a new one in there, no? if I create one object and then PUT different data, then do a get on all objects, i have no objects. Also note - no errors are thrown on the server

Comment: Does the new object have the same PK? An `AutoField` will probably create a new PK, right? Or am I confusing something here?

Comment: I would guess it will have the same `pk`, otherwise this mechanism is kind of useless (because you probably have that pk as a reference to that object somewhere). But even if it does change, if i only have one chat in the whole app and then i PUT on it, and do a GET on all the chat objects, i have none (so it didnt create a new one with a different pk)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like below?

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.user.profile.chats.all()
```

Comment: I dont think this is the issue, as it works for POST and GET